# Expose Objective C Class Extension Property in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, properties, class-extensions

Say I have the following in an Objective C implementation file (`MyVC.m`):

```
@interface MyVC ()
  @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titlelabel;
@end
```

How can I expose this private property to Swift (test) code? The following causes compiler errors:

```
extension LTConversationSelectionVC {
   @IBOutlet weak var assetBar: LTAssetBar?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this purely with Swift. However, you can expose the property in an Objective-C file in your test target and then put that in your test target's bridging header.

Add **MyVC+Tests.h** to your test target:

```
@interface MyVC (Tests)
  @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titlelabel;
@end
```

**MyAppTests-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "MyVC+Tests.h"
```

Then, in your Swift code in the test target, you can use the `titleLabel` property as expected.

```
let vc = MyVC()
vc.titleLabel.text = "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 1):

From apple doc

---

> Extensions can add new computed properties, but they cannot add stored
>   properties, or add property observers to existing properties.

---

[Apple documentation Link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Comment: Understood. So how can I expose  them? In Objective C I'd use a class extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same property-in-category trick from the Bridging Header file. Just forward any class that calls swift library. That should take care of the problem.